# Function draws Error with Postgres Databse but not on Sqlite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

So after shifting my code to heroku which is in Postgres one of my functions is drawing an error.

```
def index
    @tutor = Tutor.where(:admin => false)
    @tutor_array = []

    @tutor_array << @tutor.fees_search(params[:fees_search]) if params[:fees_search].present?
    @tutor_array << @tutor.subject_search(params[:subject_search]) if params[:subject_search].present?
    @tutor_array << @tutor.lssubject_search(params[:lssubject_search]) if params[:lssubject_search].present?
    @tutor_array << @tutor.ussubject_search(params[:ussubject_search]) if params[:ussubject_search].present?
    @tutor_array << @tutor.jcsubject_search(params[:jcsubject_search]) if params[:jcsubject_search].present?

    @tutor_array.each do |tutor|
      ids = @tutor.merge(tutor).map(&:id)
      @tutor = Tutor.where(id: ids)
    end
    @tutor = @tutor.sort_by { |tutor| tutor.rating.rating }.reverse
    @tutor = @tutor.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 2)
end
```

The particular line that gets highlighted is this 
`ids = @tutor.merge(tutor).map(&:id)`

I have read that certain calls works with sqlite and not with postgres such as doing `LIKE ?` and such. But i am pretty clueless as to whats wrong here.

Here's the error that is coming up

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in TutorsController#index
>
> PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR: operator does not exist: integer =
>   character varying LINE 1: ...M "tutors" INNER JOIN "profiles" ON
>   "tutors"."id" = "profile... ^ HINT: No operator matches the given name
>   and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts. :
>   SELECT "tutors".* FROM "tutors" INNER JOIN "profiles" ON "tutors"."id"
>   = "profiles"."tutor_id" INNER JOIN "profile_ussubjects" ON "profiles"."id" = "profile_ussubjects"."profile_id" WHERE
>   "tutors"."admin" = $1 AND "profile_ussubjects"."ussubject_id" = $2

I don't know what to search to try and resolve this since i dont even know what is it about postgres that is triggering the error.

So hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

Here's what the tutor model looks like

```
def self.fees_search(n)
    @profile = Profile.fees(n)
    if @profile.empty?
      return Tutor.none
    else
      @profile.map do |y|
        y.tutor
      end
    end
  end

  def self.subject_search(s)
    @subject = Subject.find_by_name(s)
    unless @subject.nil?
      @subject.tutors 
    end
  end
```

The other subject searches are all the same as `self.subject_search`.

I think one of the problems i have deduced would be this, in my `self.subject_search(s)` method, by testing it in the rails console, the line `@subject.tutors` is drawing the error.

In my rails console i ran `subject = Subject.find_by_name("English")` followed by `subject.tutors` and it threw the error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer = character varying
LINE 1: ...M "tutors" INNER JOIN "profiles" ON "tutors"."id" = "profile...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Why though? Im sorry but im really quite bad with postgres and i dont understand whats going on and why it worked with sqlite3. (I read that sqlite3 is not as strict as postgres but that doesn't exactly make it clear for me)

Comment: `operator does not exist: integer = character varying` You are comparing (or joining) a varchar field to an integer field.

Comment: So if i cant do @tutor.merge(tutor) which seems to be whats triggering the error (the merging) is there a way around it? Or do i have to restructure my controller code in an entirely different manner?

Comment: Your current code is probably horrible in terms of performance - you should be building a scope instead of fetching a bunch of ids separately and adding them together. Can you add the Tutor model to the question so that we can see what all those search methods do?

Comment: I've added it in. To be honest i dont actually need it to function in the exact same manner anymore since i no longer need to be able to pass all different subject searches simultaneously. I'm more concerned with the reason behind the error coming up though

Answer (score -1):

```
def index
  @tutors = Tutor.where(:admin => false).tap do |scope|
    keys = [:fees_search, :subject_search, :lssubject_search, :ussubject_search, :jcsubject_search]
    keys.each do |key|
      scope.merge!( Tutor.send(key, params[key]) ) if params[key].present? 
    end
  end.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 2)
end
```

Thats a start at least.

This line is pretty problematic:

```
@tutor = @tutor.sort_by { |tutor| tutor.rating.rating }.reverse
```

`.sort_by` pulls all the records out of the db and sorts them in Ruby. You should instead be doing a sub-select to fetch an aggregate of the ratings and using that in an order clause. (Please ask a new question if you are unsure about how to do this. Its out of scope of your original question).

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. I get `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Tutors#Index` and then it shows `PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer = character varying
LINE 1: ...M "tutors" INNER JOIN "profiles" ON "tutors"."id" = "profile...` although the line of code highlighted that is throwing the error is the `<%= will_paginate @tutor %>` that is in my index view. 

Btw why does `.sort_by` pull all the records out if its working with the `@tutor` instance variable? 

I've also updated my code to include my model if that helps. Thank you!

Comment: Quite frankly I'm not quite sure where to begin helping you. Your search functions should be returning scopes that can be chained together so that you can fetch the data effectively without a zillion database queries. What your are doing may work (kind of) but its extremely inefficient.

Comment: The `will_paginate` error is most likely because you should be passing it a collection of records and you're passing it something else like an array of ids.

Comment: `.sort_by` loads all the records from the database and then loops through them as an array. If you have assigned the collection to a instance variable or not is irrelevant.

Comment: could you point me in the right direction with regards to the search functions? i could always start from scratch but that was sort of what i arrived at which i guess as pointed out is not optimal. doing `find_by_name` is "wrong"? should i be using `.where` instead?

Comment: Yes, you should be using `.where` there are probably quite a few tutorials on the subject as well.

Comment: Alright sure i'll look to rework my code. Thanks for trying to help me out. Cheers