# Postgres: Error accessing parent through sibling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

So here are the relationships:

```
class Tutor
  has_many :subjects, through: :profile
  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
end

class Profile
  belongs_to :tutor
  has_many :subjects, through: :profile_subjects
  has_many :profile_subjects
end

class Subject
  has_many :profile_subjects
  has_many :profiles, through: :profile_subjects
  has_many :tutors, through: :profiles
end

# the join model for Profile and Subject
class ProfileSubject
  belongs_to :profile
  belongs_to :subject
end
```

Now previously it was all working perfectly fine when I was using the sqlite3 database. But upon deployment to production, I'm getting thrown errors because the database is Postgres.

Here's a simple example of what I do that throws the error

```
subject = Subject.first
subject.tutors
```

And the error that is being returned is

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer = character varying
```

As I understand (or was told) it means I'm trying to compare (or join) a `varchar` to an `integer` field.

The bigger picture of what I'm actually trying to do is something like `Subject.where("name LIKE ?", "#{name}")` and be able to find all `tutors` that have the queried `subject`. How am I able to access tutors through `subject`?

(I would just like to note that the associations were working perfectly fine on sqlite3)

Comment: Didn't you ask the same question yesterday? The awnser yesterday was wrong column type. Both columns have to be of type integer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Function draws Error with Postgres Databse but not on Sqlite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40258427/function-draws-error-with-postgres-databse-but-not-on-sqlite)

Comment: I did ask a similar question but i did not realise the root cause of the problem. Now i realised that i cannot even do something basic like stated `subject = Subject.first` followed by `subject.tutors` and why is that so? Which are the 2 columns that needs to be integers when i execute that command?

Comment: I am simply breaking down the problem and i would like to understand the root cause of the issue. Since i couldn't find anything with regards to it. Also i'm sure that if its a problem with columns it may help others who are working transitioning from sqlite3 to postgres too?

Comment: I can't extract it from your error message. Take a look at your migrations or `schema.rb` or take a look at the table definitions within postgres. All foreign keys should have the same datatype as the corresponding primary keys. A good choice is often integer. It's not a general sqlite problem. sqlite is only a little bit more gentle. You column types have to be right.

Comment: is the `tutor_id` in profile table is `integer` if not that may be the reason for your error. it shld be integer

Comment: Yup sure enough, the foreign key was not an `integer`.

Comment: Please add your `db/schema.rb` to the question.

Comment: Also take a look at the migrations in your app, have you used `belongs_to` or `references` to setup the foreign keys properly?

Comment: My tutor_id foreign key in profiles was originally a string. I've amended it now. Thanks again for trying to help!